# need to find instances which have multiple rows with the same userID and ResourceID and have a location of 1 and also have other locations

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with

```
User_ID, Resource_ID, Location_ID, INstance_ID
1,1,1,1
1,1,2,2
1,1,2,3
2,2,3,4
2,3,3,5
2,3,5,6
3,1,2,7
3,1,7,8
4,4,1,9
4,4,2,10
5,5,1,11
1,1,3,14
4,4,1,15
1,1,10,18
1,1,1,19
5,6,1,12
6,7,3,13
6,7,1,17
```

I need a list of instance_IDs where, for a specific User_ID and Resource_ID, that user/resource combination has a row in Location_ID 1 AND has rows where Location_ID is not 1.

For example:

- Instance id 1 (as user 1 has resource 1 in location 1 and location 2)
- Instance id 9 (as User 4 has resource 4 in locations 1 and location 2)

**Expected output**  (the 5 rows that have `Location_ID = 1` and there is at least one other row with same `User_ID` and same `Resource_ID` but different than 1 `Location_ID`):

```
User_ID  Resource_ID  location_ID  Instance_ID
-------  -----------  -----------  -----------
1        1            1            1
1        1            1            19
4        4            1            9
4        4            1            15
6        7            1            17
```

Comment: Have you attempted anything?

Comment: Have you looked at [Entity Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx)?

Comment: Yes I have tried something but I think it's a bit clunky.  Not sure how to add it to my question.  Is it ok to put it in an answer?

Comment: Not sure how the Entity Framework would help with this, but would be grateful if you could explain?

Comment: Aaron, thanks for your answer.  Not sure where it's gone.  I'd appreciate constructive criticism of mine if you have the time.  Or if you have a better way I'd sure appreciate it.Thanks

Comment: You need to make your requirements clearer. Above it sounds like you only wanted the first instance that met your criteria. In your current answer you yield two rows for 1,1,1.

Comment: Can you provide DDL (CREATE TABLE blah (user_ID integer... &c) and DML (INSERT INTO blah VALUES(1,1,1,2) for the rows. And then clearly indicate the result you desire from this table in terms similar to what you have written above. This will help those of us trying to help you. Take the tour and check out the "help us to help you" blog - both at the bottom left of the page.

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct
  InstancesinLocation1.user_id,
  InstancesinLocation1.resource_ID,
  InstancesinLocation1.location_ID,
  InstancesinLocation1.Instance_ID
from
  (
    select User_ID,resource_ID, location_ID, Instance_ID
    from usage
    where location_ID=1
  ) InstancesinLocation1
join
  (
    select User_ID,resource_ID, location_ID, Instance_ID
    from usage where location_ID<>1
  ) InstancesNotinLocation1
on
  (
    InstancesinLocation1.User_ID = InstancesNotinLocation1.User_ID
    and
    InstancesinLocation1.resource_ID = InstancesNotinLocation1.resource_ID
  )
;
```

```
User_ID  Resource_ID  location_ID  Instance_ID
-------  -----------  -----------  -----------
1        1            1            1
1        1            1            19
4        4            1            9
4        4            1            15
6        7            1            17
```

Comment: Aaron's answer was better (but you probably want to use it without the GROUP BY), your question was not clear at all that you expected 5 rows in the result: `SELECT User_ID, Resource_ID, Instance_ID 
FROM #x AS x
WHERE Location_ID = 1
AND EXISTS
(
  SELECT 1 FROM #x 
    WHERE User_ID = x.User_ID
    AND Resource_ID = x.Resource_ID
    AND Location_ID > 1
) ;`